# Fish Shell Default PATH

Tags: python, fish

I have a 2023 MacBook Pro that I use to run many python scripts from the terminal using Fish. I use the home-brew python3 installation to avoid messing with my system install, but I am having issues with PIP.

When I type `which python3` I get `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3` as expected

However, when I type `which pip3`, I get `/Users/username/Library/Python/3.9/bin/pip3`, which is not what I want

It looks like Fish is pulling in the path from the system Bash PATH, but I can't figure out where my computer is getting that default path from. I do not have a bash config in my home directory. In `/etc/paths.d`, the only paths added are to the cryptex system, which I don't care about.

I do occasionally use bash, so I do not want to just add the home-brew path to my .fish-config. Is my best course of action here to create a bash config, or is there something else I need to do?

Thanks for the help, I am pretty new to programming, and chatGPT has been all over the place explaining what to do.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe somebody will chime in with the "right" way to do this but I can think of 2 fixes off the top of my head: 1. manually set PATH in config.fish so that the homebrew path comes first and 2. alternatively you could never use the raw pip command, you can do `python3 -m pip <COMMAND> --user` and it should do what you want.

Comment: What Jared said -- `pip3` is bad practice these days anyhow; `python -m pip` (where `python` refers to the interpreter you want to invoke `pip` for) is your friend.

Comment: Depending on how you start `fish`, it inherits a `PATH` variable from its parent process before making any `fish`-specific additions to it.

Comment: In general, you start with `PATH` as defined by `launchd` itself, which should contain `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/bin/`, `/bin/`, `/usr/sbin/`, and `/sbin`. Anything from `/etc/paths.d` is added by `/usr/libexec/path_helper`, which is typically execute from a shell's top-level configuration file (for example, `/etc/profile`.) Anything *else* was likely added by whatever shell launched `fish` itself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Very interesting on the best practice there, that pretty much makes this a non-issue, and I'll start doing that.

Comment: @chepner when I echo the path in bash I get more than those paths. For example, my home-brew and kitty paths are added as well.

Are those added by `launchd`? How does it know to add those paths?

When I look at `/etc/profile`, it appears to run the path_helper script, but the home-brew and kitty paths are not in paths.d. 

The fish_config script does appear to pull the parent process PATH, with this line

`set -x PATH (bash -c "echo $PATH")`

Comment: that's... an odd line; it's starting a _child_ process (which presumably had its PATH initialized as a copy of fish's own PATH) and getting PATH from there. Environment variables are copied from parent processes -- the OS itself does that during the `fork()` syscall, no shell or other program has to do anything special to make it happen; so I tend to suspect whoever wrote that line `set -x PATH (bash -c "echo $PATH")` was just confused.

Comment: @samcns There are other shell-specific configuration files that might modify the value of `PATH` before startup is complete. In these files, sometimes the modification is obvious (`PATH=/some/new/path:$PATH`), sometimes not (`eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)`).